# Gradle plugin - Different Java version for sub project

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle, java-11, java-17

This is regarding multi module gradle project and JDK version support.

We have a common module(Commons) where we have a custom plugin along with other utilities which used to keep restrictions on the sub projects i.e., Microservices.

We have many Microservices using this common custom plugin to impose restrictions on build properties and tasks of gradle.

This Commons gradle project previously used to run on JDK 11.

The previous config looks following way:

Commons build.gradle

```
sourceCompatibility= JavaVersion.VERSION_11
```

plugin.gradle to build common plugin ( which is present inside subproject of Commons module)

```
allprojects {
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'java-library'
}

subprojects {
sourceCompatibility= JavaVersion.VERSION_11
targetcompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSIOM_11

}
```

Microservice build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.commons.common-plugin'

allprojects{
}
buildsript {

ext{

}

}
```

Now we want the Commons module to be on JDK 17 and the plugin to build and apply java version on Microservices should be on JDK 11.
I tried changing aroung in the above plugin.gradle for source and target comparability but end up facing same issue.

The issue i faced in Microservice during build was

```
Caused by org.gradle.internal.component. NoMatchingConfigurationSelectionException: No matching variant of com.commons

- Variant 'apiElements' capability com.commons declares as a library,packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally
  - Incompatible because this component declares a component for use during compile- time, compatible with Java17 and consumer needed a component for use during runtime, compatible with Java 11

- Variant 'runtimeElements'.... same error
```

Is there any possible way i could achieve this. If so can you suggest.

Thanks in advance.

Now we want the Commons module to be on JDK 17 and the plugin to build and apply java version on Microservices should be on JDK 11. I tried changing aroung in the above plugin.gradle for source and target comparability but end up facing same issue.